# (Tcl/Tk) Remove border around ctext mega-widget?

Tags: widget, tcl, tk-toolkit

For some reason whenever I create the ctext widget it has a really thick, black boarder around it whenever it is in focus. My code simply consists of:

```
wm withdraw .;
toplevel .main;
grid [ttk::frame .main.f] -column 0 -row 0 -sticky nswe;
grid [ctext .main.f.ct] -column 0 -row 0 -sticky nswe;
```

I've also got widths and heights specified as well as column and row configures. 
But basically I keep getting this black border around the ctext widget when in focus: http://puu.sh/g18VZ/d602a8a053.png

When it's not in focus: http://puu.sh/g193c/e6fd9c2b2b.png

I'd like to get rid of that border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tk widgets, and typically its add-on widgets like `ctext`, specify a property — the highlight thickness — which controls the width of the visible focus ring. Try configuring that to be zero.

```
.main.f.ct configure -highlightthickness 0
```